# What are the astrological combinations in a horoscope that predict the subject will be atheistically inclined?

Tags: astrology, atheism

Here, by " Atheist" i mean a person who does not have faith in God or one who does not even believe in his existence. One who does not care for religious instructions, religious scriptures etc.

My own horoscope have some combination, for example, which is supposed to make me an "Adrishta VAdi" or "one who believes in Destiny as an all-powerful entity". And, i am exactly like that.

Likewise, i want to know:

**Question: What are the astrological combinations in a horoscope that predict that the subject (jAtaka) will be atheistically inclined?**

Note 1) I am looking for planetary combinations along with their names (for eg- Kemadruma, BudhAditya, Gajakesari etc are some names of such combinations).

Looking for, some placements or combinations like malefics placed or aspecting the 5th house (known as the place of mind), the 9th house (known as the Dharma SthAna, the place of Dharma) etc. Or the RAhu-Ketu axis being placed on 1-7 houses, or 5-11 or 3-9 houses etc.

Note 2) I am looking for answers citing some authoritative Jyotisha scriptures only. I am **not** looking for answers that quote from random blog-spots.

My purpose here is- If we can get to the root of the problem beforehand, then may be we can tackle it by using the remedy-tools that Jyotisha prescribe.

Comment: There is no such thing as 100% destiny or 100% Atheism. All these are just a facade to cover up ones shortcomings. Atheism has a very high ego quotient.  100% belief in Destiny has a very low self esteem. Child when born is divine devoid of a facade. Circumstances, experiences over time makes one go from one extreme to another.

Comment: For a moment I got excited thinking it was "aesthetically inclined"

Comment: What do you mean by 'native'? Isn't astrology supposed to apply to whole humanity whether one believes in it or not?

Comment: @sv. Native means the JAtaka, the subject, whose horoscope we are discussing. The answer to ur other Q is Yes i guess.

Comment: @sv. Native is more common to use than subject. At least AFAIK. For example see the books by B.V Raman, or at least the e-mag published by them called "The Astrological Magazine". Since i have read those i tend to use native always.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But only the Astrology Dictionary defines it [that way](http://theastrologydictionary.com/n/native/). If you want you can revert my edit.

Comment: No, it's ok. A revert is not needed. @sv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually afflictions guru with rahu like guru chAnDAla yoga can make a person atheists.

It could be partial or full atheism. I would add references in upcoming days.

> Whenever you consider about Guru chandala Yoga always take notice of
>   the condition of the fifth and ninth house. If that is not bad then
>   Guru chandala loses much of its strength and maleficity. Also Jupiter
>   in nodal axis always cannot be regarded as bad. It can mean host of
>   things. Say, untraditional approach towards spiritual matters or a
>   person who does not believe in spirituality blindly he has strong
>   scientific bent of mind in every matter. Rahu defines hidden things
>   and Jupiter spirituality combine the both and you may get the complete
>   different meaning of [guru chandala yoga.](https://www.lightonvedicastrology.com/wordpress/phpBB_3.1/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1538)
>
> Jupiter and Rahu Every planet has both positive and negative traits.
>   Here the positive traits of Rahu when combined with Jupiter may make a
>   person interested in ancient philosophical lore, occultism etc. and
>   may make him follow all the external religious customs and duties. The
>   negative traits may make him a Kshudra Mantrika or he may become
>   addicted to vices. The native may become even a Naastika
>   (**atheist**).
>
> The results of Guru Chandala Yoga are given in most texts. The name of
>   the Yoga itself suggests that the native will be a Chandala or a
>   Neechakrit which mean that he will be an outcaste and will do very
>   mean acts. In my experience, Guru Chandala Yoga is found to show the
>   following results :
>   1. The native may became an agnostic or an atheist denying the existence of God.
>   2. The native may become a religious bigot hating other religions and extremely orthodox as far as his own religion is concerned.
>   3. The native may become interested in Kshudra Mantras and thereby earn money by black magic and other unorthodox means.
>   4. The native may be well versed in Vedas and Mantra Sastra and also religiously inclined, but he may be addicted to smoking, alcohol and
>   other vices.

[Reference](http://gururajeshkotekal.blogspot.ca/2016/06/this-was-probably-my-first-article.html)

Comment: please reference the scripture it is from directly in your answer. Qn has clearly asked for a strict reference-only answer, so supplying it is paramount. The answer currently only links to a forum thread directly.